# Google API address in FL returning location in NC?

Tags: api, geocoding

The following url (http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&address=6995+US+HIGHWAY+19+N,PINELLAS+PARK,FL) of an address in Pinellas Park, FL is returning a location in North Carolina. How can this be happening? What in this URL would send Google so far off course?  Even the city name should force it to return a geometric center of city, right?  At the very least the geometric center of hwy 19 within Pinellas Park.

What's odd is, if I remove the word "Park" from the (valid) city name I get closer but not in the city.

If I change the address to "6995+19+N" I get an interpolated address in Pinellas Park. But why would US and Highway confuse the API? Does the API not try permutations?

Any thoughts?

Thanks!
nw

Answer (score 0):

I think the "N" after "19" is throwing it off, but oddly [MapQuest](http://www.mapquest.com/maps?address=6995+US+HIGHWAY+19&city=PINELLAS+PARK&state=FL) appears to consider the "N" to be part of the canonical address.

Comment: How can I ensure the Google API team is involved in this process?  Sorry, all I know is the Google API forum said start using stack overflow.

Comment: Yahoo geocoding nails it too. This is a problem i'm seeing with a lot of records I'm geocoding using Google API... horrible locations.

Comment: @user2544801 - You will need to log in to your Google account, but you could try to [report an issue](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Geocoding%20API%20-%20Bug).